# Does listener gets affected when we replace secondary replica with another server in Availability Group?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability, listener, replace

I have created Multi Subnet Always On Availability Group.
Now, I need to replace secondary replica with another server in Availability Group. In this case, Do I need to re-create listener? OR The previous listener works fine?

Thank You

Comment: No, once you add the new replica to Availability group, the listener will appear there.

Answer (score 0):

The listener is a cluster ressource. If you new server is part of the cluster and is added to your availability group, it should work just fine.